# Percentage + abstract/substract question

Tags: arithmetic

[image]

My calculation was (5520*5845)*31% and I got value 10,001,964. Closest answer is 10,100,000. Is the answer right?

Thanks

Comment: -1, while this is a valid question it definitely looks like it's from some workplace recruitment test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the 5520*5845 gives the number of good units produced.  This is 69% of the total.  The rejection is 31% of the total.

Comment: brilliant! thanks. I need to wait 6 more mins to vote your answer.